# Django Best Practices: How to clean and render a form

Tags: python, django

Situation: I have a form that is used for search and I return the same form on the results page for the user to filter their results.  To get rid of garbage input, I have implemented a clean_xxx method.

Unfortunately, the form is returned on the results page with the garbage input even though it was cleaned.  How can I get the clean data to display?

Here are a few ideas:

1. In the clean_xxx method, set the self.data.xxx = cleaned_xxx value
2. Reinitialize a new form with the cleaned_data.

forms.py:

```
    SearchForm:
    def clean_q(self):
    q = self.cleaned_data.get('q').strip()
    # Remove Garbage Input
    sanitized_keywords = re.split('[^a-zA-Z0-9_ ]', q)
    q = "".join(sanitized_keywords).strip()

    #TODO: Fix
    self.data['q'] = q

    return q
```

views.py

```
    search_form = SearchForm(params, user=request.user)
    if  search_form.is_valid():
        # Build the Query from the form
        # Retrieve The Results

    else:
        # For errors, no results will be displayed
        _log.error('Search: Form is not valid. Error = %s' %search_form.errors)

    response = {
                'search_form': search_form...
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Show your code: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Reinitialization looks good enough. First option is a hack from some point.

Comment: @Marcin I've simplified my code for you to review

Comment: Are you tried to trace what happens with q in each step of  clean method?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you return from a clean_xxx method is what will be displayed. So, for example:

forms.py:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    def clean_q(self):
        return "spam and eggs"
```

In the above example the field will say "spam and eggs".

If it doesn't do that, then odds are the trouble is in the validation logic of your method.

Comment: The clean_q function works fine but the issue is that I return the same search_form once it's been validated and the q is the same.

For instance: q = Stackoverflow ()()()
clean_q = Stackoverflow

The form displays q as Stackoverflow ()()().  Is there a better way to display the cleaned_data q on the page?